# Validate select with jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to add a validation to the select box, but I'm getting an error `has no name assigned` i don't know where I'm wrong in assigned naming...

I'm using the MaterializeCSS Framework and I suspect that something in it is conflicting with jQuery Validation.

My scripts version.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="modules/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/localization/messages_pt_BR.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.10.3/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></scrip
```

Select box.

```
  <form id="transporter" name="transporter" action="transporter/new" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">more_vert</i>
      <select id="statusTransporter" name="statusTransporter">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione uma situação de atividade para seu transportador</option>
        <option value="ativo" id="activeStatusTransporter">Ativo</option>
        <option value="inativo" id="inactiveStatusTransporter">Inativo</option>
        <option value="pendente" id="pendingStatusTransporter">Pendente</option>
      </select>
      <label>Situação do transportador:</label>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Validation rules.

```
  jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
  });

  var transporterPublish = $("#transporter");

  transporterPublish.validate({
    lang: 'pt_BR',
    errorClass: 'error',
    errorElement: "div",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      var placement = $(element).data('error');
      if (placement) {
        $(placement).append(error)
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    },

    rules: {
      statusTransporter: {
        required: true
      }
    }
  });
```

Ajax that will start after click button.

```
      $('#publish-transporter').click(function () {
        var payload = {
          statusTransporter: $('#statusTransporter').val()
        };

        if (transporterPublish.valid()) {
          $.ajax({
            url: "/transporter/sucess",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            complete: function (data) {
              swal(
                'Good job!',
                'You clicked the button!',
                'success'
              )
            }
          });
        }
        return false
      });
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: It would help to know which version of jQuery and the jQuery validation plugin you are using.

Comment: Also, there is no element with the id "transporter" in your HTML example

Comment: @Connum I'm sorry, I forgot to add my plugins version and element id form it to the question, I'll add it now.

Comment: So what does the swal() function do? Please provide a working code snippet that demonstrates your problem... It's very hard to help you in any way currently.

Comment: @Connum this swal() it's just a modal sucess which will be displayed after ajax send sucess it does not interfere with validation

Comment: Well, I can't see any problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/o3dtdpkx/

Comment: @Connum Your jQuery is in different version, my version is on 3.2.1 he says in my console has no name assigned but in your example, its running believe it's mine framework

Comment: I think I read somewhere that jQuery-validate is currently not compatible with 3.1.1

Comment: @Connum really? this validate it is working in input field only in my select box i'm having trouble validating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157197/discussion-between-connum-and-smachs).

Comment: Are you showing us the **rendered** HTML markup or the markup from your framework?  Look at the actual code in the browser DOM to make sure the `name` attribute is retained when the page is rendered.